# Too long query with more than 1 subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with this mysql query:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('Kantor ', o.nama) AS nama,
    IF( sj.jenis = 1, CONCAT(sj.sebutan, ' ' , sj.nama), sj.nama) AS sebutan, 
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(fj.id)
        FROM
            tbl_formasijabatan fj
        WHERE
            fj.sebutanId = sj.id AND
            fj.status    = 1     AND
            fj.orgId     = o.id
    ) AS total

 FROM
     tbl_organisasi o
     RIGHT JOIN tbl_formasijabatan fjj ON fjj.orgId = o.id
     RIGHT JOIN tbl_sebutanjabatan sj  ON sj.id     = fjj.sebutanId
 WHERE
     o.id = 1 AND
     o.unitKerja > 0
 GROUP BY
     o.nama,
     sj.nama
```

This query is very long, takes 66 seconds just to get 330 rows.

How can I speed up data retrieval at least within 1-10 seconds?

Well your comment is very helpful for me.

If it requires data I will send the database.

thank you

Comment: Place Index for the Primary Key columns for the used tables.Indexes helps in performance and fast retrieval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the times you are just missing an index on the columns in the `where` clause and in the `join` clause.

You should put an index on

- tbl_formasijabatan.orgId
- tbl_formasijabatan.sebutanId
- tbl_organisasi.unitKerja

  ```
  alter table `tbl_formasijabatan` add index(`orgId`);
  alter table `tbl_formasijabatan` add index(`sebutanId`);
  alter table `tbl_organisasi` add index(`unitKerja`);
  ```

you can also name the index, but that would be the fastest way. Your query should be quite fast after that, since it is not that much compicated. Actually the group will consume the most time after all, since it needs a temporary table. If you want to dig deeper here you might have a look here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html

**Bottom Line:** don't start with a index shutgun action. You should only put index on those columns, that are used for joins and in a lots of where statements. Otherwise you would degrade performance again. A good starting point would be

http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/WEBINAR-tools-and-techniques-for-index-design.pdf

Comment: thank you for the answer. your answers resolve my problem. Now my query is much faster, before I have not used the index, but now use it, it turns out I so know what the index function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could move that SUBQUERY to a join, that should give you improvement in performance, try something like:

---

```
SELECT CONCAT('Kantor ', o.nama) AS nama, if(sj.jenis = 1, CONCAT(sj.sebutan, ' ', sj.nama), sj.nama) AS sebutan, X.total 
FROM tbl_organisasi o 
RIGHT JOIN tbl_formasijabatan fjj ON fjj.orgId = o.id 
RIGHT JOIN tbl_sebutanjabatan sj ON sj.id = fjj.sebutanId 
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(fj.id) total, fj.id 
    FROM tbl_formasijabatan fj 
    WHERE fj.sebutanId = sj.id 
    AND fj.status = 1 
    AND fj.orgId = o.id 
    GROUP BY fj.id) X 
ON X.id = fjj.id 
WHERE o.id = 1 AND o.unitKerja > 0 
GROUP BY o.nama , sj.nama
```

---

Sorry for bad formatting, give it a shot and let me know.

Comment: Joining against the subselect like this should be better performance wise (although indexes are needed as well). However I think @Kartikya has made a minor typo here. In the subselect I think it should return fj.ordId rather than fj.id, and also group by fj.ordId rather than fj.id. Further the line AND fj.orgId = o.id should be removed.